# MySQl запрос, как правильно.

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!

Есть такой запрос:

```
"UPDATE dle_post set short_story='<br>1' WHERE id='19'"
```

Добавляет в самый конец `short_story: <br>1  id 19.`

Как сделать чтоб добавило во все `id` таблицы `dle_post` в самый конец `short_story: <br>1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128335/sql-update-all-values-in-a-field-with-appended-string-concat-not-working

Comment: Вот так как я понял будет запрос:

   UPDATE dle_post SET category = CONCAT(category,',1')

Спасибо за УРЛ, где все объяснили.